# how edit a method in list view?

Tags: android, listview

I want to create a `ListView` of audio files. I have a problem when I play audio in list. When I select an audio from the list, the audio previously playing doesn't stop..
   I know `MediaPleyer` has method `stop()` but I do not know how to edit method `stop()` in  My java structure...

java codes:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 int []audio={R.raw.salavat_1,R.raw.salavat_2,R.raw.salavat_3,R.raw.salavat_4,
       R.raw.salavat_5};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    Myadapter adapter=new Myadapter(getApplicationContext());
     seekBar=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public class Myadapter extends BaseAdapter implements Runnable
{
    LayoutInflater myInflater;
    public Myadapter(Context context) {
        myInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return audio.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return  position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder Holder;

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            Holder=new ViewHolder();
            convertView=myInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null);
            Holder.play=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Imag_play);

           Holder.play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            play(audio [position]);

                }

        });

           convertView.setTag(Holder);




        }
        else
            Holder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();



        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return convertView;
    }
      ----------
     public void run() {
        int currentPosition= 0;
        int total = mp.getDuration();
        while (mp!=null && currentPosition<total) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                currentPosition= mp.getCurrentPosition();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return;
            }            
            seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
        }
    }


    protected void play(int audio) {


            if(seekBar.getProgress() > 0) {
                mp.start();
                return;
            }
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), audio);
        mp.start();                     
        seekBar.setProgress(0);
        seekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
        new Thread(this).start();




        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Comment: when u click one then stop the previous one thats all :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to edit the `MediaPleyer.stop()` method.

Instead adjust your `play(int audio)` method to first check if an audio track is playing and if one is, stop it.

You could do this at the start of your `play(int audio)` method by calling `MediaPlayer.isPlaying()`. If this is true call `MediaPlayer.stop()`. You can then clean your MediaPlayer object with `mp = null`

EDIT: Something like:

```
protected void play(int audio) {
    if(seekBar.getProgress() > 0) {
        mp.start();
        return;
    }

    // Stop and clean the MediaPlayer if there is already a track playing
    if(mp.isPlaying() == true) {
        mp.stop();
        mp = null;
    }

    mp=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), audio);
    mp.start();                     
    seekBar.setProgress(0);
    seekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
    new Thread(this).start();

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Note: I have not run this code.

Comment: Where are you stuck? You say you want to edit the method `stop()`, what would you like it to do?

Comment: but when edit   method above in java code  ...my app has Exception

Comment: I am still not sure why you are trying to edit the `MediaPlayer.stop()` method, it is almost certainly not the best thing to do.
Some context would be useful: What are you trying to achieve by editing the method? What Exception is returned? What code are you using to edit the method?

Comment: PS I assume you mean 'override' when you say 'edit'. You can't actually edit the MediaPlayer methods.